# How to Implement a Promise-Based Queue with Task Prioritization in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, priority-queue

I am trying to build a promise-based queue in JavaScript where each task returns a promise that resolves when the task is done. The queue should process tasks one at a time, waiting for each promise to resolve before starting the next.

However, there is a complexity: each task has a priority, and higher-priority tasks should jump the queue. If a higher-priority task is added, it should be the next task to run after the currently-running task completes, regardless of its position in the queue.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
class Task {
  constructor(fn, priority) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.priority = priority;
  }
}

class PriorityPromiseQueue {
  // implementation needed
}
```

The `PriorityPromiseQueue` should process `Task` objects, calling each `Task.fn` function in priority order. `Task.fn` will return a promise.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to implement this `PriorityPromiseQueue`? I've considered using an array and keeping it sorted by priority, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way, especially for large numbers of tasks.

Comment: A "promise-based queue" is a FIFO queue as the data structure and a runner that consumes tasks from the queue. Now to make that a "promise-based priority queue", you keep the runner as-is and just swap out the data structure literally for a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Do you need auto-running added tasks after the queue is complete?

Comment: Also it's not clear whether a task can change it's priority

Answer (score -2):

A simplest implementation could be this. Yes it's still a sorted array. AFAIK the current JS implementation use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort which is adaptive so inserting a new task to already sorted queue is linear.

The reason that I doubt there will be a promise queue more than 10000 items. Real case scenarios will go totally OK with it imho.

```js
class Task {
    constructor(fn, priority) {
        this.fn = fn;
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}

class PriorityPromiseQueue {

    tasks = []
    constructor(...queue) {
        this.add(...queue);
    }
    add(...queue) {

        const sort = () => this.tasks.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);

        // allow change priority at runtime and resort the queue
        queue.forEach(task => {

            let priority = task.priority;

            Object.defineProperty(task, 'priority', {
                get: () => priority,
                set: val => {
                    priority = val;
                    sort();
                }
            });

        });
        this.tasks.push(...queue);
        sort();

    }
    remove(task) {
        const idx = this.tasks.indexOf(task);
        if (idx === -1) {
            return false; // not in the queue
        }
        Object.defineProperty(task, 'priority', {
            value: task.priority
        });
        this.tasks.splice(idx, 1);
        return true;
    }
    async run() {
        if (!this.tasks.length) {
            return;
        }
        const task = this.tasks.shift();
        await task.fn();
        return this.run();
    }

}

let taskId = 1;
const createTask = () => {
    const id = taskId++;
    return new Task(
        () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
            () => console.log('task', id, 'complete') + resolve(),
            Math.random() * 3000
        )),
        Math.random()
    );
};

const tasks = Array.from({ length: 5 }, _ => createTask());

const queue = new PriorityPromiseQueue(...tasks);

queue.run().then(() => console.log('QUEUE COMPLETE'));

//move the last task to the top after running the queue so the 5th task should be 1st or 2nd
tasks.at(-1).priority = 1;

// add and remove tasks at run time
const task = createTask();
queue.add(task);
queue.add(createTask());
queue.remove(task);
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient. Also it does not work when you `.add()` tasks to a queue which is empty (has finished running).

Comment: @Bergi write better instead of spamming. also there's no requirement to auto-run tasks. what do you mean inefficient? any arguments. looks rather like spamming with downvotes

Comment: Feedback on solutions/ideas isn’t spam, it’s feedback.

Comment: @DaveNewton no arguments is not feedback. maybe could you explain what's inefficient and even pretty? i'm ok with my solution being lame and deleted just explain pls

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Given the OP wrote "*I've considered using an array and keeping it sorted by priority, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way*", I don't think this is a useful answer to show them the code of how to keep a sorted array. Calling `.sort()` every time an item should be processed has awful time complexity.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, will add some note to the answer. also promise queue aren't giant so there's no problem to use an array instead of a real queue.

Comment: I’d question re-sorting every time the queue is run; worst-case scenario is a no-op-that-takes-time if no tasks are added, best case is if a “lot” of mixed-priority tasks are added during a task run. Since the OP is specific about “large number of tasks” It may be that efficiency matters (or OP may be optimizing prematurely). With no real context regarding actual needs (e.g., what about low-priority tasks being starved) it’s not clear the code provided really addresses the question being what the OP already considered.

Comment: @DaveNewton re-sorting is already fixed without your help, but thanks for your comment, will be considering, i'm learning JS so my answers are kinda exercises for me

Comment: @DaveNewton the more you right constructive comments the more i learn from you